# Signing Assembly requires Administrator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've a lot of projects having assemblies signed with a .snk key.

After resetting windows 10 the compilation of these projects failes giving me the error:

```
1>ALINK : error AL1019: Errore nei metadati durante la creazione dell'assembly: Accesso negato.
```

I avoided this problem running visual studio as administrator and it works.
(It works either unchecking the signature of assembly)

Anyway before resetting windows I had no need to use "Run As Admin", my user is already administrator. (I always use VS2015 update 2)

How can i compile signed assemblies running Visual Studio in normal mode?

Comment: Ewww, assembly signing. Barf. Before reformatting you probably had UAC turned off.

Comment: *Yup ...*  In any case, "signing an assembly" is something that "not everyone is allowed to do," because, if it were, well, "any script-kiddie's script might do it."

Comment: @Phill: UAC turned off and rebooted gives me the same error.

Comment: @Mike: i agree it is a privileged operation but i'm administrator and don't want to "run VS as admin". Before resetting system i was allowed to compile signed assemblies now something has changed but don't know what.

Comment: I don't think you need admin access to _sign_ an assembly, but you may need admin access in order to access the _key_.  Or you may need admin access to _write_ the signed assembly.

Comment: "Betcha yer right" on that second sentence, Stanley ...!